# Customize System Notification for connected VPN in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-notifications

I have created a vpn application using Flutter. I want to customize the android notification to hide disconnect button when VPN is connected, currently I am getting this notification.
[VPN System Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CiVc.png)

Comment: Provide the code

Comment: i am not very familiar with the android native side so i could not guess which part of the code you need. If you can specify the part you want I can provide. Link of the library that I've been using:  [openvpn_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/openvpn_flutter) @JunaidKhalid

Answer (score 0):

Use this library and enjoy it!

```
flutter_local_notifications: ^17.0.0
```